# Is it possible to have country specific Command Lists in MS Teams bot?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

We have a bot available in MS Teams. The bot is available for Enterprise US and Canada users. We are implementing Command Lists in the bot. We are maintaining separate JSON file for EN-US and FR-CA cultures. Is there any way to implement the command list only for US users(i.e. for EN-US)?

Kindly Suggest.

Comment: Do you want to use a single JSON to implement country specific command lists? If Yes then its not feasible. You can use different country specific JSON files to achieve so. Please refer below link: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-faqplus/tree/master/Manifest/EndUser

Comment: Thanks Prasad.  I am using two different json files in my project.. For en-us users, I have to populate 4 bot commands.  For fr-ca users, populate only two commands. Is it possible?

Comment: For example if you have 4 bot commands for en-US and 2 for fr-CA. When you will change the language from en-US to fr-CA, it will show you remaining/missing two commands in default language(for eg. en-US) apart from those two fr-CA commands.

Comment: Thanks for your response Prasad.  Is it possible to hide all the 4 commands in fr-ca?

Comment: No, its not possible to hide

Answer (score 0):

You can use different country specific JSON files to achieve so. Please refer below link: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-faqplus/tree/master/Manifest/EndUser

For example if you have 4 bot commands for en-US and 2 for fr-CA. When you will change the language from en-US to fr-CA, it will show you remaining/missing two commands in default language(for eg. en-US) apart from those two fr-CA commands.